# Mac OS X automatically starting programs

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

When I boot my Mac, I have some programs that start up automatically. Where can I see the list of these programs to disable some?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Login items

Most of those can be found under

*System Preferences - Accounts - Login Items*

Unlock the preferences (left bottom corner) and remove them by pressing the small <kbd>-</kbd> button.

[image]

#### Launch Agents

Developers should place their apps into the Login items. OS X also has `launchd` which can launch agents. So basically these are things that are also loaded when the system starts.

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
/Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
/System/Library/LaunchAgents   Mac OS X Per-user agents.
```

You **shouldn't mess with those** on a normal basis, because removing something might render your system unstable. But at one time I installed something that only could be removed by deleting it from my `LaunchAgents` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Go to system preferences / accounts / your account and then click the 'logon items' tab.
Those are the application that run automatically when you log on.

Comment: You might also need to click the padlock icon at the bottom-left corner if it is locked.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth looking for an uninstall (unix executable file) for a particular program that's appearing when you start up your mac.

I had installed some software by Promethean (ActivManager) to connect to a smartboard but the software got on my nerves every time I started the mac.

I found the files in the LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons folder but was a bit reluctant to just delete them - I used finder to locate the application folder which contained an "uninstall" program which, when I ran it, cleaned up and removed the offending software.

This might be a better solution for some people.